# Axon Event Handler not working on a different microservice

Tags: microservices, event-sourcing, axon, event-driven, axon-framework

I was implementing event-driven CQRS concept using Axon framework. I created two separate microservices and their own two write and read databases.

I am publishing an event in ms-1 and now I want to handle that event in ms-2, so that I can persist it in my read DB. But the @EventHandler is not working in my ms-2. The events are published on the AxonServer, I can see the updates there.

And yes, I do have @Component on the EventHandler class in ms-2. Also, I am running AxonServer on docker.

The @EventHandler works fine when it is in the same microservice.

My axon-framework dependency is 4.5.8 and google guava's is 30.1.1-jre

Comment: I suppose you're pointing both services at the same Axon Server instance? Is the (Spring ?) @Component annotated class in ms-2 located in the same (or sub)package of the SpringBootApplication class?
You can also check the AxonServer UI (typically localhost:8024) to see if both applications are connected. Click on an application in the overview to see details. You should see an Event Processor registered for ms-2

Comment: Yes, both services are connected to the same server. I can see them on the AxonServer UI. but the events are not being handled by ms-2.

Comment: Are the events declared in a shared jar, or does each service define its own classes? It may help to provide a bit more information. The most trivial examples have 2 services talking to each other just fine. There must be something you do differently here.